# Noun Clause with That (with preposition or not?)

Tags: clauses

Which one is correct? or there is no difference?

Jan is worried that his son won't come home.

Jan is worried **about** that his son won't come home.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The first is fine, but not the second. The preposition "about" does not normally license (permit) a declarative content clause (your _that_ clause) as complement.

Comment: The second sentence should read *Jan is worried about **the fact that** his son won't come home.* With that change, they effectively mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, it is correct to say:

"Jan is worried that his son won't come home."

The second sentence is not correct in its current state. There are, however, a few ways in which we can make it correct and still use "about", for example:

a) "Jan is worried about **the fact that** his son won't come home."

b) "Jan is worried about **the possibility of** his son **not coming** home."

c) "Jan is worried about **his son, who may never** come home."

Hope this helps!

Comment: As far as I understand, we can't use any of the prepositions before that. For example, of, with, on, etc. So that's not specific for only about, also all the prepositions.

correct : I was aware that you were outside.

incorrect: I was aware of that you were outside.